# php error for validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter form validation. but i have problem, that is, password matches does not work for me. When callback method shows "email does not exist",
that time, all validation are working fine.

```
public function forget_password() {

    $this - > form_validation - > set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_verifyUser',
        array(
            'required' => 'You must enter your email!',
            'valid_email' => 'Enter valid email!',
            //'is_unique' => ' is already exists'
        )
    );
    $this - > form_validation - > set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|matches[confirm_password]|required|min_length[6]',
        array(
            'required' => 'You Must Enter Password',
            'matches' => 'Password Must Match with Confirm_password',
            'min_length' => 'Minimum contain 6 charaters',
        )
    );
    $this - > form_validation - > set_rules('confirm_password', 'confirm_password', 'trim|required',
        array(
            'required' => 'You Must Enter Password',
        )
    );
    if ($this - > form_validation - > run() === true) {
        $this - > load - > view('forget-password');
        $this - > load - > view('template/footer');
    } else {
        $this - > load - > view('forget-password');
        $this - > load - > view('template/footer');
    }
}

public function verifyUser() {

    $email = $this - > input - > post('email');
    if ($this - > e_model - > login_view($email)) {
        $result = $this - > e_model - > reset($email);
        $this - > session - > set_flashdata('flsh_msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">New password created successfully!</div>');
        redirect(current_url());
        return true;
    } else {
        //$this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','Email does not exists!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need comma (,) after the last object of the array.

Comment: Yes, I had remove it, But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a simple mechanism to validate the passwords..check whether it will work with urs too..

```
public function validation() {
        $this->db->select('name,email,type,id');
        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));

        $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));


        $result = $this->db->get('custsp');

        if ($result->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $result->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done so much lengthy coding for form validation....!
Don't use your customize code when you are already using inbuilt libraries

use one simple validation rule for email availability

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|is_unique[users.user_email]');
```

Where "users" is your table name and "user_email" is your field
AND for password check...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconfirm]');
```

That's it!!
I hope you will get it.For detail you should refer documentation of form validation properly.